# How do i add the number of guesses into my game? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to coding and have had alot of help with this project. I have to make a game for a school project. The game is simple, you just have to pick the right cell in the table, what i dont understand is how i would be able to count the number of guesses the player takes. I also have another problem where i so not understand how i would be able to alert the player a direction when they pick the wrong cell, for example if they chose the wrong cell an alert would come up and tell them north or something like that. My code is here if you would like to look at it.

```js
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';

function Start() {
  Table.style.display = "block"
  MainMenu.style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;

}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});

function tableText(col) {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined')
    el = event.srcElement
  el.style.backgroundColor = col
}


let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex - 1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
document.querySelector('#R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex).onclick = () => {
  tableText('green');
  alert("correct");
}

function hideAll() {
  Table.style.display = "none"
  MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}

function gameReset() {}

function required(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please input your name");
  } else {
    name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    Start()
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 45%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Tableheader {
  border: 0px solid white
}

.TableCell {
  background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.TableCell:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="MainMenu">
  <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
    <ul>
      <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
      <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
      <li><input type='text' name='text1' id='text1' /></li>
      <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
      <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="Table">
  <div id='playerName'></div>
  <h2>Hurkles</h2>
  <p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
  <table>
    <table id="tableID" class="center">
      <tr>
        <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
        <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
        <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
        <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
        <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
        <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
        <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
        <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
        <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
        <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
        <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
        <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
        <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
        <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
        <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
        <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
        <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
        <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
        <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
        <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
        <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Counting the number of guesses is simple: add `let guesses = 0;` at the top of your script, outside any functions. Then put `guesses++;` inside the cells' click handler function.

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry but i am not very good at coding, could you show me how that is done even though it should be simple. I thought i had done it but i have not. Sorry about that

Comment: I'm sorry but if you can't understand these simple instructions then how is doing it for you going to help in the long run? You'd just immediately get stuck at the next small obstacle. Like implementing the direction hint, which is a magnitude more complex than counting guesses. You simply need practice.

Comment: Set guesses in the outer scope, then increment by +1 inside the click handler. STOP using `onclick` inline attributes, same as you hopefully don't use inline CSS `style`. JS and CSS should be in one place only, and that's their respective tags or files. Use addEventListener instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. PS: Guess one cell? Hard to call this a *game*.

Comment: and don't forget to reset guesses back to `0` inside `gameReset`

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code, added `numberOfClicks` and `colNames` as a global variables (outside any methods so all methods can use them).

I also removed the `id` attribut on each cell, and instead added two `data-*` attributes: `data-row` and `data-col`. So now you can get the row and column indexes of each clicked cell, through `el.dataset.row` and `el.dataset.col`.

I removed all classes on the table cells, because `th` means "table header" which should mark all the ... well .. headers.

I changed so that you don't change the background style, but instead add a `.green` or `.red` class.

I didn't solve the question for you, but I gave you the tools so you can fill in the rest. Clicking on a cell calls `tableText()` method that checks if it's the correct cell, otherwise `tableText()` will call a `giveHint()` method.

Add `numberOfClicks++` to the correct method, and fill out `giveHint()` with code of your own.

---

If you want to reset the game, use a `gameReset()` method.

You should have created the whole table with javascript, instead of HTML, but that's beyond your knowledge for now. That would make it a lot easier to reset the table again, i.e. remove all classes from the cells.

```js
let rowIndex, colIndex, numberOfClicks;
const colNames = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'];

function tableText(color) {
  if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
    el = event.srcElement;
    let clickedRow = el.dataset.row;
    let clickedCol = el.dataset.col;
    
    if (reachedWinCondition(clickedRow, clickedCol)) {
      triggerWinCondition(el);
    } else {
      el.classList.add(color);      
      giveHint(clickedRow, clickedCol);
    }
  }
} 

function triggerWinCondition(el) {
  el.classList.add('green');
  alert("you found it");
}

function reachedWinCondition(clickedRow, clickedCol) {
  return clickedRow == rowIndex && clickedCol == colIndex;
}

function giveHint(clickedRow, clickedCol) {
  // do something with clickedRow, clickedCol, rowIndex, colIndex
  console.log({clickedRow}, {clickedCol})
}

function gameReset() {
  numberOfClicks = 0;
  randomizeHurklesHidingSpot();
}

function randomizeHurklesHidingSpot() {
  colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
  rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
  
  console.log('col:' + colNames[colIndex - 1], 'row:' + rowIndex);
}

gameReset();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 45%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

th {
  border: 0px solid white;
  font-weight: normal;
}

td {
  background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td.red {
  background-color: red;
}

td.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

.button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="Table">
  <div id='playerName'></div>
  <h2>Hurkles</h2>
  <p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
    <table id="tableID" class="center">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>H</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>J</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="1" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="2" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="3" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="4" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="5" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>6</th>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="6" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>7</th>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="7" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="8" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="9" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="1" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="2" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="3" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="4" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="5" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="6" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="7" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="8" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="9" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
        <td data-row="10" data-col="10" onclick="tableText('red')"></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: OP is a beginner that doesn't even know how to add `numberOfClicks`. I left the onclicks to to avoid further confusion. Obviously, the OP had a teacher that instructed stuff like `gameReset`, and that approved the inline javascript.

Answer (score 0):

for click count create variable then increase the value every cell clicked, for `hint` you need to extract row and column from the cell id then compare with right answer.

```js
Table.style.display = "none";
MainMenu.style.display = "block";
var name = '';
var counter = 1;

function Start() {
  Table.style.display = "block"
  MainMenu.style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('playerName').innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + name;

}
var input = document.getElementById("text1");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("submit").click();
  }
});

let colIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
let rowIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 1;
let answer = 'R' + rowIndex + 'C' + colIndex;
console.log('col:' + ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'][colIndex - 1], 'row:' + rowIndex);

document.querySelectorAll('.TableCell').forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    clickCount.textContent = counter++;
    if (el.id == answer) {
      el.style.background = 'green';
      alert("correct");
    } else {
      el.style.background = 'red';
      var cell = el.id.match(/R(\d+)C(\d+)/)
      var row = parseInt(cell[1])
      var col = parseInt(cell[2])
      if (row != rowIndex) {
        hint.textContent = row > rowIndex ? "Up" : "Down";
      } else {
        hint.textContent = col > colIndex ? "Left" : "Right";
      }
    }
  });
})


function hideAll() {
  Table.style.display = "none"
  MainMenu.style.display = "block"
}

function gameReset() { }

function required(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var empt = document.forms["form1"]["text1"].value;
  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please input your name");
  } else {
    name = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    Start()
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 0px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 45%;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Tableheader {
  border: 0px solid white
}

.TableCell {
  background-color: rgb(252, 142, 215);
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.button {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.TableCell:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://storage.pixteller.com/designs/designs-images/2019-03-27/05/simple-background-backgrounds-passion-simple-1-5c9b95bd34713.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="MainMenu">
    <form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="required(event)">
        <ul>
            <h2>Hurkles the Game</h2>
            <p>Type in your name and click start to begin</p>
            <li><input type='text' name='text1' id='text1' /></li>
            <li class="rq">*Required Field</li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" id='submit' value="Submit" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="Table">
    <div id='playerName'></div>
    <h2>Hurkles</h2>
    <p> Click a Cell to Find Hurkles</p>
    <p><strong>Click Count: <span id="clickCount">0</span> | Hint: <span id="hint"></span></strong></p>

    <table id="tableID" class="center">
        <tr>
            <td id="R0C0" class="Tableheader"></td>
            <td id="R0C1" class="Tableheader">A</td>
            <td id="R0C2" class="Tableheader">B</td>
            <td id="R0C3" class="Tableheader">C</td>
            <td id="R0C4" class="Tableheader">D</td>
            <td id="R0C5" class="Tableheader">E</td>
            <td id="R0C6" class="Tableheader">F</td>
            <td id="R0C7" class="Tableheader">G</td>
            <td id="R0C8" class="Tableheader">H</td>
            <td id="R0C9" class="Tableheader">I</td>
            <td id="R0C10" class="Tableheader">J</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R1C0" class="Tableheader">1</td>
            <td id="R1C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R1C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R2C0" class="Tableheader">2</td>
            <td id="R2C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R2C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R3C0" class="Tableheader">3</td>
            <td id="R3C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R3C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R4C0" class="Tableheader">4</td>
            <td id="R4C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R4C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R5C0" class="Tableheader">5</td>
            <td id="R5C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R5C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R6C0" class="Tableheader">6</td>
            <td id="R6C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R6C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R7C0" class="Tableheader">7</td>
            <td id="R7C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R7C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R8C0" class="Tableheader">8</td>
            <td id="R8C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R8C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R9C0" class="Tableheader">9</td>
            <td id="R9C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R9C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="R10C0" class="Tableheader">10</td>
            <td id="R10C1" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C2" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C3" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C4" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C5" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C6" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C7" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C8" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C9" class="TableCell"></td>
            <td id="R10C10" class="TableCell"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="reset" onclick="hideAll()">Start</button>
</div>
```